# A more optimised solution

Tags: python-3.x

I have a list of words.I need to find the anagrams and return a list of set of anagrams
For ex:
Input: `['cat','act','dog','ogd']`
output: `[{'cat','act'}, {'dog','ogd'}]`

I was able to code correctly but i need a more optimised alternate solution.Can anybody please help me?

```
from collections import defaultdict 

def group(words):
    d = {}

    for word in words: 
        key = "".join(sorted(word))
        d.setdefault(key, set()).add(word)

    sets = list(d.values())

    return sets
```

I need a more optimised solution

Comment: Hi there. A better place for this is [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/). They help you optimise your code.

Comment: You're importing `defaultdict`, but you're not using it: Make d be a `defaultdict(set)`, and then just do `d[key].add(word)`.

Answer (score 0):

Anagrams don't care about order. Sets come to mind when considering that fact. Problem is sets are not hashable and don't account for repetitions and can be slow to compare since you can't use hashing.

To be fast, this solution attempts to avoid sorting and prefers hashing:

First we create a function to hash fast:

```
import collections
def anagram_hash(word):
    return frozenset(collections.Counter(word).items())
```

Then we use a defaultdict to aggregate fast in a single go:

```
anagrams = collections.defaultdict(list)
for word in words:
    anagrams[anagram_hash(word)].append(word)
```

Comment: Won't this group words such as `good` and `dog` together though as the grouping key will be the same...?

Comment: well, there is no frozendict so I give up. The sorted(tuple(...)) is just too much :|

Comment: @JonClements used a counter object with some hashing :|

Comment: Yeah... I can't think of any way to improve what the OPs got... it's readable and is not going to be that inefficient that much can be optimised anyway... The overhead of a function call, creating a counter and converting it to a frozenset set is going to be a lot optimised that the OPs approach :(